# Path to file in LINUX C programing

Tags: c, linux, path

Good day.
Im creating a multi-thread program which will be reading a basic date about process which you will point using PID number.
And one of the threads should read information from "`status`" file. This file is in `/proc/NUMBER_PID/status`
So I wrote this `pthread` function. But Im still geting an error. Can anyone point where is the problem ?

```
pthread_create(&pth[1],NULL,odczyt,&pid);
.....
##define NUMBER arg
void *odczyt(void*arg)
{
    char*bufor;
    FILE *plik;
    plik=fopen("/proc/NUMBER/status","r");
    if(plik==0){
        perror("Error: Blad otwarcia pliku");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((fgets(bufor,200,plik))!=0)
    {
        printf("%s",bufor);
    }
    fclose(plik);
    free(bufor);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: what exactly is your error?

Comment: @maciekkov have you tried it just an unthreaded version? how are you getting /proc/NUMBER to be the pid? NUMBER won't expand into the pid the way you have it.

Comment: @maciekkov you need to provide a program we can compile

Comment: NUMBER is replaced at compile time.  To put a number in a string, use strncat.

Comment: Error is just my perror message.

Comment: @stark that is good idea .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of issues in your code,

```
##define NUMBER arg
/* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ what is this define? */

void *odczyt(void*arg)
{
    char*bufor;
  /*^^^^^^^^^^^^  this is never malloc'd */

    FILE *plik;
    plik=fopen("/proc/NUMBER/status","r");
  /* you never use ^^^^^^^^ the pid */
```

you are not replacing the number with the PID

```
    if(plik==0){
        perror("Error: Blad otwarcia pliku");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((fgets(bufor,200,plik))!=0)
    {
        printf("%s",bufor);
    }
    fclose(plik);
    free(bufor);
 /* ^^^^^^^^^^^ free'ing something you never malloc'd */
}
```

try:

```
void *odczyt(void*arg)
{
    char bufor[256];
    FILE *plik;
    char statusFile[256];
    snprintf(statusFile, sizeof(statusFile), "/proc/%u/status", *(pid_t *)arg)); 
    plik=fopen(filename,"r");
    if(!plik){
        perror("Error: Blad otwarcia pliku");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((fgets(bufor, sizeof(bufor),plik))!=0)
    {
        printf("%s",bufor);
    }
    fclose(plik);
}
```

Comment: Its working :) Thank you .
But edit improve your code, just a gramar. ')' and the end snprintf function 
and rename filename to statusFile inside plik=fopen....

Comment: And could you explain me why even when i made this 
plik=fopen("/proc/argv[1]/status","r");  it was not  working ?
and in shell i was typing like second parametr PID my firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open file `/proc/arg/status`, because you use processor to create path. You should to put pid in path in runtime using e,g [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

Comment: Better use `snprintf` because `sprintf` might buffer-overflow.

Comment: Tak zrobiłem dzięki :)

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong (read *carefully* [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...)

```
plik=fopen("/proc/NUMBER/status","r");
```

You probably want (if you care about your own process):

```
plik = fopen("/proc/self/status", "r");
if (!plik) {perror("/proc/self/status"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

<sup>(the failure of above `fopen` is unlikely, but could happen if you are out of file descriptors)</sup>

or, if you care about some other process of given `pid` (declared as `pid_t pid;` and suitably computed), you need to computer a string (e.g. `pathname` in below code chunk) containing the appropriate path (what a *shell* would expand from `/proc/$pid/status`; read about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)):

```
char pathname[80];
snprintf(pathname, sizeof(pathname), "/proc/%d/status", (int)pid);
plik = fopen(pathname, "r");
if (!plik) {perror(pathname); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

Compile your code with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

<sup>(you really need to know how to use the debugger, so take several hours or days to learn [how to use `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html))</sup>

Comment: Actually  I chacked your code and something is wrong could your look at it ?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc,char**argv)
{ 
    char bufor[100];
 char*bufor2;
 snprintf(bufor,sizeof(bufor),"/proc/%d/status",(int)argv[1]);
 FILE *plik;
 
 plik=fopen(bufor,"r");
 if(plik==0){
  perror("Error: No such file or directory");
  exit(1);
 }
 while((fgets(bufor2,200,plik))!=0)
 {
  printf("%s",bufor);
 }
  
 
 fclose(plik);
 
}

Comment: As I told you **use the debugger**